# 403-error when calling external WCF-service (.svc)

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, https, http-status-code-403

I have a web application running .NET Framework 4.7.1 which makes calls to an external WCF-service (.svc) over https. I have added the references using standard `Add Service Reference` from within Visual Studio which generates a client and adds the necessary bindings to `web.config`.

The application runs fine on my local machine as well as in a staging environment (running on IIS) and is able to make successful calls to the external WCF-service without any issues.

However, when deploying the application to Azure in a "Web App" (Windows) the application is no longer able to make requests to the external WCF-service. I receive the following error:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1463
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +56

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +159
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +353
...
```

The remote service isn't using any certificates for client authentication nor is it using any IP-whitelisting. The server certificate is valid (the remote service is also hosted in Azure, i.e. `xxxx.azurewebsites.net`) - I am pretty confident that it is something in the Azure environment that is causing the error (even if the error message itself seems to be coming from the remote server). Maybe a proxy or something is messing with the request?

I have created a new blank MVC-project with a single controller and the service reference to isolate the issue, and the problem persists.

I've tried changing the binding configuration in `web.config` to several different settings for `<security mode="[...]">` but nothing works - always the same error.

I've collected a `Network Trace` but I am unable to read anything useful from it.

I guess calling external WCF-services is supported by the Azure-platform?

Please help me troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I think it's because you didn't assign permissions to Azure RABC correctly. This document details Azure RABC and I think it was helpful to you[What is Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)